# electron toggleDevTools() method is undefine

Tags: electron

In my electron code I want to open window with browser developer tools when the window is loaded for that is I call toggleDevTools(); on load but it showing toggleDevTools() is undefined.

what is the solution please help !

Comment: toggleDevTools is a method of webContents, did you call it on a window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you calling it from a view? (an html file)
It must be called in the main process (main.js) and it is a BrowserWindow method.

`win.webContents.toggleDevTools();` where `win` is your BrowserWindow object.

If you need to open the dev tools from the view, look into ipcRenderer